# How to deserialize JSON having a Date type field to POJO.

Tags: java, date, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I'm working on a REST api using Jersey+Jackson.

I want to convert JSON --> POJO.

My **Pojo** class is having a **Date field** called **'created'**.

In a String **'jsonUser'** i have json representation of my **Pojo**.

Now when i use following code to convert JSON representation to Pojo object :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
Pojo oldUser = mapper.readValue(jsonUser, Pojo.class);
```

I get following error :

```
Exception: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Timestamp from String value '2013-07-29 11:41:00.0': not a valid representation
```

Jackson is not able to **deserialize** `String` representation to `Date` object.

How can i configure **Jackson** to do that?

Comment: "How can i tell Jackson to do that?" That's funny!!
Any ways what is the datatype for Date filed in your pojo?

Comment: @Sandiip Patil it's java.lang.Date

Comment: Try java.util.Date. I have similar pojo and I am converted and then re-collecting from JSON and it works fine for me.

Comment: Also while setting the time to the field what are you using? I mean u setting system time?? how are you setting that?

Comment: You welcome. Dont forget to upvote if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Problem might be in date conversion. 
Just do it in following way:

```
public class Pojo
{
private String created;
private Date createdDate;

//getter methods. 

//setter methods
public void setCreated(String created)
{
  this.created = created;
  //Logic for converting MySQL-String representation to desired
}

//mapper config
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true );
}

Pojo oldUser = mapper.readValue(jsonUser, Pojo.class);
```

- Create a `mapper` which can avoid exception if values are not present.
- Create POJO with `created` as `String` field and `createdDate` with
  `Date` field.
- In setter for 'created', write logic for conversion of `String to Date`.
- JSON will assign `String` to POJO properly by calling setter method on `created`.
- In setter, the `string-date conversion` logic will take care of `createdDate` field.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just store it as long. To get the long value use dateObj.getTime(); To create a date object from long use new Date(longVal)